# Asus zenfone 2 laser factory reset bypass owner's mail authentication

Tags: factory-reset, google-account, asus-zenfone-2

I'm using Asus Zenfone 2 laser Android device. When I bought the device one of my office colleague did the set up for me. Yesterday I did factory reset. After reset I tried to access my mobile. It asked me to use Owner's Google account which I used before in that device for sync. I do not have that mail id nor do I have that person's contact.

I have the bill for the phone. Is there anything I can do to bypass this authentication?

Comment: That's called "factory reset protection" or, in short, FRP. I've never dealt with it personally, but others have: Please see our [factory-reset tag-wiki](/tags/factory-reset/info) (yes, our tags have wikis :) and follow up to [Bypass “Verify your (Google) account” after resetting](/q/127739/16575) plus [other helpful posts](/search?tab=newest&q=frp%20answers%3a1).